# How can I reroute a port through DNS?

Tags: dns, ports

I have the following domains:

1.) Negative.Zero (not owned yet, waiting for public release; see [here](http://www.instra.com/en/domain-names/newgtld/zero-domain-registration/zero))

2.) qns.net

I'm running (2) apache2 servers, each on different machines. One listens on port 80, and the other on 9001. Each of them are port forwarded through OpenWRT Backfire. I want to be able to access the one running on 9001 through the URL htp://negative.zero/ and the other through the URL htp://qns.net without having to specify a port like this: htp://negative.zero:9001/

How can I do this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

*Note: I intentionally wrote htp:// because of the link limit if you don't have 10 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

DNS itself cannot force a client to change the port number of the request. Therefor, I only see two solutions. Either you use mod_proxy to have the server sit behind the first one on port 80, OR use name based virtual hosts, and get rid of the second server/port.

You have two solutions:
  * use mod_proxy
  * use name based virtual hosts

**Option 1:**
 Unfortunately I have no experience with mod_proxy. You may consult the documentation at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html

**Option 2:**
 You can use Name Based Virtual Hosts to have both requests on the same server.

Documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html
Examples: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ExampleVhosts

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<!-- qns.net *.qns.net www.qns.net -->
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.qns.net
   ServerAlias qns.net *.qns.net
   DocumentRoot /www/qns.net
</VirtualHost>

<!-- negative.zero www.negative.zero *.negative.zero -->
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.negative.zero
   ServerAlias negative.zero *.negative.zero
   DocumentRoot /www/negative.zero
</VirtualHost>
```

If you need to run SSL you need to have more than one external IP, since the whole HTTP/1.1 request is encrypted.

> > As a rule, it is impossible to host more than one SSL virtual host on the same IP address and  port. This is because Apache needs to know the name of the host in order to choose the correct certificate to setup the encryption layer. But the name of the host being requested is contained only in the HTTP request headers, which are part of the encrypted content. It is therefore not available until after the encryption is already negotiated. This means that the correct certificate cannot be selected, and clients will receive certificate mismatch warnings and be vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks. You can check the documentation at: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts